# Printing the contents of a DIV

Tags: jquery, printing-web-page

I have a div setup that hold a series of field names and field values.

The field values are loaded dynamically from the return of an ajax call.

They are populated and I am able to see them on the screen.

I have a print button that uses the jquery.printElement.js toolkit, and when pressed, the contents of the DIV are printed - EXCEPT, the values of the textboxes are not being printed, only the placeholder values.

When i inspect the page (view source) the values for the textboxes are not being shown, just the placeholder text - I am thinking this is where my issue is coming from.

Is there a way to force the values to be shown when I perform a view page source?

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
  <input id="sheetAddress" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" maxlength="50">
</div>
```

I am loading the values using jquery

```
$('#sheetAddress').val(record[6]);
```

I have tried using the build in debugger of the PrintElem routine, and it too does not show the values of the fields.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input id="sheetAddress" name="sheetAddress" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" maxlength="50">
```

the name was added, and it prints now